# Display duplicates of an array like "Number x repeats x times

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How can I change my code so I can get only one number and duplicate times from an array?

I tried the classic method but it shows like "2 repeats 2 times" x2 lines, "0 repeats 3 times" x3 lines etc., when I just want only one time "2 repeats 2 times; 0 repeats 3 times" etc

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] array = {2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7};
   Arrays.sort(array);

   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     int count = 0;
     for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
       if(array[i]==array[j] && i != j){
         count = count + 1;
         System.out.println("elements" + array[i] + " repeats" + count + " times);
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array gets sorted, it only needs one loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int index = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    while (index < array.length - 1) {
        if (array[index] == array[index + 1]) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            if (counter > 1) {
                System.out.println("element " + array[index] + " repeats " + counter + " times");
            }
            counter = 1;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if (counter > 1) {
        System.out.println("element " + array[index] + " repeats " + counter + " times");
    }
}
```

It compares each element with the next one. If they are equal the counter is incremented, if not if it is greater than 1 this means that there were duplicates and it prints the line:

```
"element " + array[index] + " repeats " + counter + " times"
```

If it is not greater than 1, the index is incremented and the counter resets to 1.
The same with a for loop:

```
for (index = 0; index < array.length - 1; index++) {
    if (array[index] == array[index + 1]) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        if (counter > 1) {
            System.out.println("element " + array[index] + " repeats " + counter + " times");
        }
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more comment why this works and why his try is insuccesfull.

Comment: This is the one :-D Thanks forpas. You've got any example that works in for-loop?

Comment: Why that for-loop doesn't work? I've tried to build this project and it doesn't show the ouput..

Comment: What for-loop doesn't work? I tested it and it works.

Comment: @alender The answer you accepted does not work for this array: `{2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7, 45}`

Comment: I've tried it on my array and it's working.. Why are you saying this? Maybe is something I'm missing...

Comment: Try it on this array: `{2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7, 45}`. I added 45 a the end, so it should display 45 2 times.

Comment: Your while-loop works, but for-loop doesn't. How so?

Comment: Both work. Just replace while with for. They do exactly the same thing. Did you try just the for loop without the rest of the code?

Comment: No no, i've tried with some changes to understand the logic. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Every item is compared to the next. If they are equal the counter is increased. If they are not equal, the code checks the counter: if it is > 1 this means that the previous items were duplicates and it prints the message and resets the counter to 1 so the next iteration will start for the new item. When the loop finishes, the code checks again the counter: if it is > 1 this means that the previous items were duplicates and it prints the message.

Comment: I've tried to declare variables index and counter in the for loop like I saw in other examples and that's why I thought this code doesn't work fine. I've got some difficulties to understand when should I declare them in and outside  the loops:-) Beginner stuff but thanks a lot!

Comment: @forpas do you know why for array [code] int[] array = {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -2,-1} this code doesn't show the counter for highest value from the array?

Comment: This code counts duplicates. It does not count the highest value.

Comment: @forpas but 1 is a duplicate element of that example array and still don't count it, i've tried...

Comment: don't worry, i've found the solution with another for loop to find the highest value and count it if it's repeats! Thanks for perspective @forpas!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```java
      int[] array = { 2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7
      };
      Arrays.sort(array);

      int count = 1;
      int v = array[0];
      for (int i = 1;i < array.length;) {
         while (i < array.length && v == array[i++]) {
            count++;
         }
         if (count > 1) {
            System.out.println(v + " occurs " + count + " times.");
         }
         v = array[i - 1];
         count = 1;
      }
```

Here are some additional ways that don't require sorting.

```java
   public static void method2() {
      int[] array = { 2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7
      };
      Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
      for (int i : array) {
         // If the map contains the number, bump the count
         if (map.containsKey(i)) {
            int count = map.get(i)+1; // increment count
            map.put(i,count);        // put it back
         } else {
            map.put(i, 1);  // intialize count to 1
         }
      }
      // Now go thru the map and display only the numbers when the value is > 1
      for (Map.Entry<?,Integer>  e : map.entrySet()) {
         if (e.getValue() > 1) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " occurs " + e.getValue() + " 
        times.");
         }
      }
   }
```

The next method, takes advantage of the Stream capability starting with Java 8.

```
   public static void method3() {
      int[] array = { 2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7
      };

      Arrays.stream(array)
            // Convert the integers to an Integer object.
            .boxed()
            // group the values into a Map<Integer, Integer> where the key is
            // the number
            // and the value is the count.
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> k, Collectors.counting()))
            // grab the entry set of that map
            .entrySet()
            // convert it to a stream
            .stream()
            // filter for entrysets where the value > 1
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
            // and forEach entry set that passes the filter, print out the
            // number and its count.
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(
                  e.getKey() + " occurs " + e.getValue() + " times."));

   }
```

Comment: This does not work for: `{2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7, 45}`

Comment: Can you explain it in some words that a beginner can understand? :-)

Comment: @alender  As requested

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 or above, you could group the elements in a map by the number as key and how many times it appears as value. After that, you can filter and display only the elements that appear more than one time.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {2, 0, -12, 0, 23, 45, -4, -5, 2, 23, 0, 9, -7};

        Arrays.stream(array)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println("elements " + e.getKey() + " repeats " + e.getValue().size() + " times"));
    }
}
```